# Views Conditional Range

Tags: views

I would like to be able to input a range in my views conditional ,

e:g:

```
If (age > 0 && age <= 10)
{
 ...
}
```

How can I achieve this using [Views_Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional)?

Answer (score 1):

In Views, you can add multiple Filters for the same field/column, and configure each one separately. So you can add one filter for "age is greater than 0", and "age is less than or equal to 10". Filters use an AND operator by default, so you should be all set with that, but FYI you can also change the operator to OR (you can also mix operators).

The only limitation may run into is whether or not "is greater than" and "is less than or equal to" are available options in the filter handler for the particular field you're filtering on. Number fields can do that, as far as I know... but strings can't (for example).